# RuntimeError: Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #1 'self' in call to _th_set_

Tags: pytorch

Here is a part of my code :

```
use_cuda = not args.no_cuda and torch.cuda.is_available()

device = torch.device("cuda" if use_cuda else "cpu")

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5, 1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 50, 5, 1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4*4*50, 500)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(500, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        ...
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1) 
model = Net().to(device)

def train(args, model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch):
    model.train()
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(federated_train_loader):
        model.send(data.location) 
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
        output = model(data)
        model.get() 
        if batch_idx % args.log_interval == 0:
            loss = loss.get() 
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx * args.batch_size, len(train_loader) * args.batch_size,
                100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), loss.item()))
```

I would like to modify this model by a pretrained resnet :

```
model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
model.to(device)
```

But its triggers:

```
RuntimeError: Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #1 'self' in call to _th_set_
```

The error was in `model.get()`

here is the part of get method

```
        def module_get_(nn_self):        
            for element_iter in tensor_iterator(nn_self):
                for p in element_iter():
                    p.get_()
            if isinstance(nn_self.forward, Plan):
                nn_self.forward.get()
            return nn_self
        self.torch.nn.Module.get_ = module_get_
        self.torch.nn.Module.get = module_get_
```

How can I solve this pb. Thks

Comment: In which line this error?

Comment: @Hamzah I edit my post. Thks

Comment: Is this a distributed setting? To the best of my knowledge, neither get or send are methods of pytorch nn.Module, but are present in torch.distributed. Maybe it is better to clarify it in the question.

Comment: Please post about the `get` method